# ASP Accordion Expanded

Tags: asp.net, list, accordion, expand

I'm using Accordion control of Ajax Control Toolkit, and Panes, Headers, Contents populated from code behind (c#). There are some links in panes, some headers are direct links. When I click one of them, it just expands first element. I just wanted to expand the Pane which I clicked the link.

Comment: your comment was really helpful

Comment: Sorry - I was only trying to make a point here - my comment, like your question, lacks 99% of what the other party need. Could you provide some details on what you call a "pane", an "accordion" and maybe show code and/or screenshots.

Comment: If you don't know a "pane" and an "accordion", I think you can't help me. Thanks for trying. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Please take my comments as a general guidance as to how to present a question. One angle that you're probably not considering is that both "panes" and "accordions" have been implemented by a number of libraries, and this detail will determine how your question is answered. Also, can you verify the [asp-classic] tag - is it possible that you meant [asp.net] instead?

Comment: Ok, I'm using Accordion control of Ajax Control Toolkit, and Panes, Headers, Contents populated from code behind (c#). There are some links in panes, some headers are direct links. When I click one of them, it just expands first element. I just wanted to expand the Pane which I clicked the link. Is it clear enough?

Comment: This is much better. Consider editing your initial question to add the details.